# Incorrect datetime value: Tue Jul 27 2021 20:47:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I trying to store date in mysql workbench as "2022-07-27T15:17:50.401Z" but while executing the  query it gets converted to the brlow and give this error

I want to store date as this format - "2022-07-27T15:17:50.401Z"

and what should I put the datatype of that column

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'Tue Jul 27 2021 20:47:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' for column
```

EDIT

this is the object -

date range: { from: 2021-07-27T15:52:34.173Z,
to: 2022-07-27T15:52:34.173Z },

and the query is :

```
Insert into table (from , to) Values (from, to);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241479/discussion-on-question-by-pradeep-jaiswal-incorrect-datetime-value-tue-jul-27-2).

Answer (score 1):

Your invalid DATETIME value must be converted using [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2021-07-27T15:52:34.173Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f')
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE('2021-07-27T15:52:34.173Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 2021-07-27 15:52:34.173000                                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=394be85a2d79017abb3b765b9a7ef8f4)*